# event listener of removefeature does not get executed when a feature is removed from the vectorsource

Tags: openlayers

as shown in the below posted code, i want to execute some side effects in `evtListener` when a feature is removed from the vector-source.
at run time, when `deleteSelectedGeometry` function is invoked, the geometry gets deleted, but the event-listener `evtListener` posted below in the code is never invoked, hence, the
side effect code in it can not be executed.

to solve this issue, i registered for the event `clear` of the vector source, when i do clear the vector source, the listener registered to liste to the event `clear` gets executed.

please let me know why the event-listener registerd to listen to `removeFeature` is not getting executed

**code**

```
deleteSelectedGeometry() {
    if (this.#featureRecentlyHovered != null) {
        this.#vectorSource.removeFeature(this.#featureRecentlyHovered);
    }
}

#evtListener = (evt) => {
    if (this.#featureRecentlyHovered != null) {
        this.#initWatcherOnDeleteGeometry.value = useWatchedVarUpdat();
    } 
}

registerOnRemoveFeatureFromVectorSource() {
    this.#keyOnRemoveFeature = this.#vectorSource.once('removefeature', (evt) => this.#evtListener(evt));
}
```